# Recommendations for Promotion at Conferences

Tags: discussion, conference

I'm visiting from the far off, foreign land of Politics.SE.  I'll be attending a political science conference later in the year and I wanted to discuss Politics.SE with some of the attendees, who would be excellent potential answerers on our site.

[user4012](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/users/115/user4012) mentioned that Skeptics may have done a similar kind of promotion in years past.  Do you have any recommendations for promoting at conferences? What was your experience like? Did you achieve any results?

My original post on Politics.SE is [here](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3470/can-i-use-the-stackexchange-logo-to-promote-the-site). It's explicitly about the legality of using StackExchange logos and other material to promote our site. If anyone has some insight into that topic, please don't hesitate to answer.

Comment: [Larian](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/users/386/larian-lequella) is your man for this